# Running entire JHipster generated web application from IntelliJ's sprint boot run configuration

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jhipster, web-development-server

I generated a web application with `JHipster` and imported it in `IntelliJ IDEA`. When I run the `Spring Boot` main class everything seems fine and the application is supposedly made available on port `8080`:

```
----------------------------------------------------------
    Application 'MyApp' is running! Access URLs:
    Local:      http://localhost:8080
    External:   http://192.168.56.1:8080
    Profile(s):     [swagger, dev]
----------------------------------------------------------
```

However, if I navigate to this URL, I only get a blank white page. Running the web application from the terminal using `npm start` or `yarn start` works fine and tells me that the application is available on port `9000` and the URL is opened in a new browser tab:

[image]
All good.

I tried configuring the `npm` launch configuration template in `IntelliJ`:
[image]

However, that doesn't work either. Nothing is printed on the `Console` window and it tells me `Connection refused: Connect` even though it seems to actually run the command successfully but then gets an error unlike the terminal.

[image]

How do I make `IntelliJ` start the web application "correctly" using the run configuration, preferably via the `Spring boot` main class (`MyAppApp`) without running anything on the terminal to get up and running like `npm start` does? I want both, the frontend and backend to initialize this way (just everything needed for the web application to function).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by running the `spring boot` run configuration and an `npm start` configuration in `IntelliJ` at the same time. This was pretty obvious to be honest but I can debug `TypeScript` as well now which is good enough after all.

Answer (score 2):

Webpack server on port 9000 (`yarn start`) runs only the frontend and proxifies all API calls to port 8080 where listens the spring boot app. So you must run both if you want hot reloading of both client and server.

If you don't want to run both, you must build client first using `yarn webpack:build`, then you can run only the spring boot app but of course the client part will be static.

See https://www.jhipster.tech/using-angular/

Comment: You didn't really answer the question. How do you run the frontend and backend at once via the spring boot main class run configuration so that you can debug `TypeScript` as well? Currently by running `yarn start` you can't do that.

Comment: @BullyWiiPlaza You cannot do this. TheIDEA main class configuration can only compile and reload Java code not JS.

Comment: If you're using Ultimate edition you should ask JetBrains for other suggestions.